# why is `(((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")` evaluated to "HEY!"?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, programming-languages, continuations, callcc

I am reading *The scheme programming language* and seeing this example in continuation section:

```
(((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!") => "HEY!"
```

I cannot figure out why this expression evaluating to "HEY!"

According to the [CSE 341 lecture notes](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/15-scheme-continuations.html):
`(call/cc expr)` does the following:

1. Captures the current continuation.
2. Constructs a function `C` that takes one argument, and applies the current continuation with that argument value.
3. Passes this function as an argument to `expr` --- i.e., it invokes `(expr C)`.
4. Returns the result of evaluating `(expr C)`, unless `expr` calls `C`, in which case the value that is passed to `C` is returned.

So, in this example `(((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!") => "HEY!"`

1. the current continuation of `call/cc` is

   ```
   (lambda (v)
      ((v (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")
   ```
2. the constructed function `C` is

   ```
   (lambda (y)
      ((lambda (v)
          ((v (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")) y))
   ```
3. invokes `((lambda (x) x) C)`
4. returns the result of evaluating `((lambda (x) x) C)`, which is `C` itself

Therefore, `(call/cc (lambda (k) k))` evaluates to `C`. The whole expression will be:

```
(((lambda (y)
  ((lambda (v)
      ((v (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")) y)) (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")
```

i.e. `((C (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")`, which is `("HEY!" "HEY!")`.
This will result in an exception: `Wrong type to apply: "HEY!"`, meaning applying a non-function value "HEY!".

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll attempt to break it down.

Starting with

```lisp
(((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")
```

the result of evaluating `((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) x))` needs to be a function, and it's called with the argument `"HEY!"`.

```lisp
(call/cc (lambda (k) k))
```

calls an anonymous function and passes it a continuation, a special function that when called, will return its argument to where `call/cc` returns to. The anonymous function just returns that continuation without calling it. Call that continuation `kont`, and substitute it for the whole `call/cc` expression:

```lisp
(kont (lambda (x) x))
```

That continuation is now called, with an anonymous function that takes one argument and returns it as its argument. That function is thus the result of evaluating the continuation. So basically `((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) x))` is equivalent to `(lambda (x) x)`. Which is then called with the argument `"HEY!"`, which it then returns.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly `kont` is?  `(define kont #f) (((call/cc (lambda (k) (set! kont k) k)) (lambda (x) x)) "HEY!")` using this code and expecting `(kont (lambda (x))` in repl gives me "HEY!", but I get an error: `In procedure get-output-string: Wrong type argument in position 1 (expecting open output string port)`.

Comment: @happybzy just an abbreviation for 'the continuation returned by `(call/cc (lambda (k) k))`'.

Comment: Anyways you need `(kont (lambda (x) x))` for your version that saves the continuation and calls it again later.

Comment: I though I got this, but `(((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) 2)) "HEY!")` is an error because 2 is not a procedure. (And the `x` handed to the lambda is indeed a procedure.)  I expected it to be like `((lambda (x) 2) "HEY!")`. What am I missing?

Comment: @molbdnilo The `((call/cc (lambda (k) k)) (lambda (x) ...))` expression has to return a function because of its position in the entire thing.

Comment: @molbdnilo this answer skips a step, which might've been the reason for your confusion. the call `(kont[] f)` *(pseudo-notation!)* first _returns_ that `f` into the location `[]` *(pseudo-notation!)* as directed by `kont[]`, which here is `[]` right after that `kont[]` itself (i.e., replacing the `kont[]` in the code). so it goes `((kont[] id) "hey") => ((id id) "hey") => (id "hey") => "hey"`. and with your example, it's `((kont[] (const 2)) "hey") => (((const 2) (const 2)) "hey") => (2 "hey")`.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, I think I get it now. (But I've said that many times...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I read it, expressed in CPS:

```
(define (identity& v k)
  (k v))

(define (call/cc& f& k)
  (f& (lambda (v ingnored-k) (k v)) k))

(define (repl-print v)
  v)

(call/cc& identity&
          (lambda (v&)
            (v& identity&
                (lambda (v2&)
                  (v2& "HEY!" repl-print)))))
```

So the current continuation of `call/cc&` call is:

```
(lambda (v&)
  (v& identity&
      (lambda (v2&)
        (v2& "HEY!" repl-print))))
```

1. The first round, `v&` is a continuation function that, when called, will pass the value not to its own continuation (ignored-k), but the continuation of `call/cc&`. Thus the above will be called if `v&` gets called.
2. `v&` gets called with `identity&` as result. Thus the original continuation gets called and this time `v&` is `identity&`
3. `v&` (`identity&`) gets called with `identity&` as argument and continuation `(lambda (v2&) ...)`
4. `v2&` is `identity&`and it gets called with `"HEY!"` and the continuation `repl-print`
5. `repl-print` gets called with `"HEY!"`. The text gets shown and the program terminates.

Notice that #1 and #2 ends up calling the same continuation with different values. If it was the same you would have a loop.